# Ionic 3: How to fix ion-list-header at the top and scroll only list-item, not ion-content?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ion-list on page, and I want to scroll only list-item, not the whole ion-content.

**Here is my code:**

```
<ion-content scroll="false" no-padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>Select your Status</ion-list-header>

        <ion-scroll style="width:100%; height:100vh" scrollY="true">
           <ion-item>
               <h2>Available</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>Busy</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>At school</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>At the movies</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>At work</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>Battery about to die</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>Can't talk, text only</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>In a meeting</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>At the gym</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>Sleeping</h2>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item>
               <h2>Urgent calls only</h2>
           </ion-item>
       </ion-scroll>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

I want to fix list-header "Select your status" and scroll only other list-items, but it hides list-header even when I have set scroll="false" to ion-content.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to add `position: sticky;` to the `ion-list-header`s CSS. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) for the browser support.

Comment: @Phonolog tried it, still not working.

Comment: It worked for me by adding `position: sticky;`, as suggested by @Phonolog and also `top: 0px;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do as such:

html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-list-header>Select your Status</ion-list-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content scroll="false" no-padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-scroll style="width:100%; height:100vh" scrollY="true">
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Available</h2>
      </ion-item>
      ...
    </ion-scroll>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Position your `ion-list-header` inside of `ion-header` to make it sticky

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add "sticky" attribute in ion-list-header tag.

Applicable in ionic 2, ionic 3, ionic 4

Comment: I believe you're referring to 'ion-item-divider'